# xpath syntaxis inconvenient starts-with

Tags: xpath

I have the following question related to the syntax in XPATH, I appreciate your kind indication of where I have the error:

If I use: `//@id`, it returns the correct result, if I want to use `starts-with` to make it more specific, it does not work for me, I'm trying with:

```
//*[@id(starts-with(.,17))]
//*@id[starts-with(.,17)]
```

where can be the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempted XPath doesn't work because `@id()` isn't valid XPath expression, maybe you meant to use `[]` to construct a predicate here. As for your second attempt, the following part isn't recognized as valid XPath expression : `*@id`. The other thing is `starts-with()` expect both parameters to be of type string. Correcting those errors will get you an XPath that will correctly return element where `id` attribute value starts with `17` :

```
//*[@id[starts-with(.,'17')]]
```

The above XPath can be simplify a bit as follows :

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'17')]
```

If you mean to return the `id` attribute itself instead of the element, then the XPath need to be modified as mentioned in the other answer :

```
//@id[starts-with(.,'17')]
```